# Find nearest number to specific word using regex in R

Tags: r, regex

I want to find the nearest number between a specific word in a string. Lets say the word is "week" (FYI: since "week" is a subset of "weeks", "weeks" can be used too)

The word "week" will appear only once. By closest number, I mean the number of words (not characters) between "week" and the number.

```
eg1 <- c("100 this is 40 weeks old")
eg2 <- c("this is week 40, 52 years")
eg3 <- c("omg its been 40 blah weeks, not sure though could be 1000")
eg4 <- c("omg its been 40 blah weeks (30 maybe), not sure though could be 1000")
eg5 <- c("Week 20 is not far away")
```

This is the output I would like

```
[1] 40
[2] 40
[3] 40
[4] 30
[5] 20
```

How can I get this using regex in R?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do:

```
eg <- c(eg1,eg2,eg3,eg4)
mapply(function(x,y,z)regmatches(x,list(y))[[1]][which.min(abs(z-y))],
        eg, gregexpr("\\d+",eg),regexpr("week",eg),USE.NAMES = FALSE)
```

EDIT:

if at all we are to look how close they are from either the start or the end of the word week we could do:

```
mapply(function(x,y,z)regmatches(x,list(y))[[1]][which.min(abs(z-ifelse(z>y,y,y-4)))],
      eg, gregexpr("\\d+",eg),
  regexpr("week",eg),USE.NAMES = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 2):

May be this would help where `split` the 'eg' by the punctuations, get the index of 'week' as well as the numbers and subset the number based on the minimum distance between the index

```
as.integer(sapply(strsplit(eg, "[[:punct:] ]+"), function(x) {
     i1 <- grep("week", x)
     i2 <- grep("\\d+", x)
  x[i2][which.min(abs(i2-i1))] }))
#[1] 40 40 40 30 50
```

NOTE: Here, we are counting the distance as number of words instead of number of characters

#### data

```
eg1 <- c("100 this is 40 weeks old")
eg2 <- c("this is week 40, 52 years")
eg3 <- c("omg its been 40 blah weeks, not sure though could be 1000")
eg4 <- c("omg its been 40 blah weeks (30 maybe), not sure though could be 1000")
eg5 <- c("example 5: 40 a week 50")
eg <- c(eg1, eg2, eg3, eg4, eg5)
```

Comment: While this properly extracts integers, it doesn't grab the *nearest*.

Comment: Hi @akrun, I added another example to better clarify my question

Comment: @ctwheels It is baesd on the OP's example

Comment: @akrun but the OP did specify *nearest* - this prioritizes integers that precede the keyword.

Answer (score 2):

This checks which sequence of digits ends (if before "week") or starts (if after "week") closest to "week" (in terms of number of characters). The position of week is taken as the position of "w" for digits before week and the position of "k" for digits after week.

`gregexpr` gives the location the match starts, as well as the length of the match (in the "match.length" attribute). This is used to get the relevant locations of "week" and digits, then `which.min` is used to get the index of the digits match closest to "week" and then the substring of the original string is taken from the start of the closest match to the end.

```
eg <- 
  c("100 this is 40 weeks old",
    "this is week 40, 52 years",
    "omg its been 40 blah weeks, not sure though could be 1000",
    "omg its been 40 blah weeks (30 maybe), not sure though could be 1000",
    "example 5: 40 a week 50",
    "1000000000 weeks is 1/79 the age of the universe")

mapply(function(digi, weeki, eg){
    digi2 <- digi + ifelse(digi < weeki, attr(digi, 'match.length') - 1, 0)
    weeki2 <- weeki + ifelse(digi > weeki, attr(weeki, 'match.length') - 1, 0)
    closest.i <- which.min(abs(digi2 - weeki2))
    closest <- digi[closest.i] + c(0, attr(digi, 'match.length')[closest.i] - 1)
    substr(eg, closest[1], closest[2])
  },
  gregexpr('\\d+', eg),
  gregexpr('week', eg),
  eg)

# [1] "40"         "40"         "40"         "30"         "50"         "1000000000"
```